# Remove newlines in svgs created with custom components in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I made the svg as a component and inserted it, but a strange newline is caught. I want to print on a single line without newlines, but how do I do that? (I'm using the chakra ui, but it's not very relevant.)

- When creating a custom component, I also tried creating span, but the result was the same.

```js
const PersonIcon = ({ fill = 'none' }) => {
  return (
    <svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill={fill} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M6 6C6.63899 6 7.26362 5.82405 7.79492 5.49441C8.32622 5.16477 8.74031 4.69623 8.98484 4.14805C9.22937 3.59987 9.29335 2.99667 9.16869 2.41473C9.04403 1.83279 8.73633 1.29824 8.2845 0.878681C7.83267 0.459123 7.257 0.173401 6.63029 0.0576455C6.00358 -0.0581101 5.35398 0.00129984 4.76364 0.228363C4.17329 0.455426 3.66871 0.839943 3.31371 1.33329C2.95871 1.82664 2.76923 2.40666 2.76923 3C2.76923 3.79565 3.10961 4.55871 3.7155 5.12132C4.32139 5.68393 5.14315 6 6 6ZM6 6.85714C3.9975 6.85714 0 8.00571 0 10.2857V12H12V10.2857C12 8.00571 8.0025 6.85714 6 6.85714Z"
        fill="#2D3748"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

const LockIcon = ({ fill = 'none' }) => {
  return (
    <svg width="12" height="16" viewBox="0 0 12 16" fill={fill} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M9.5 5.99975H9V3.49976C9 2.70411 8.68393 1.94104 8.12132 1.37844C7.55871 0.815826 6.79565 0.499756 6 0.499756C5.20435 0.499756 4.44129 0.815826 3.87868 1.37844C3.31607 1.94104 3 2.70411 3 3.49976V5.99975H2.5C1.96974 6.00033 1.46137 6.21123 1.08643 6.58618C0.711479 6.96113 0.500579 7.4695 0.5 7.99975V13.4998C0.500579 14.03 0.711479 14.5384 1.08643 14.9133C1.46137 15.2883 1.96974 15.4992 2.5 15.4998H9.5C10.0303 15.4992 10.5386 15.2883 10.9136 14.9133C11.2885 14.5384 11.4994 14.03 11.5 13.4998V7.99975C11.4994 7.4695 11.2885 6.96113 10.9136 6.58618C10.5386 6.21123 10.0303 6.00033 9.5 5.99975V5.99975ZM8 5.99975H4V3.49976C4 2.96932 4.21071 2.46061 4.58579 2.08554C4.96086 1.71047 5.46957 1.49976 6 1.49976C6.53043 1.49976 7.03914 1.71047 7.41421 2.08554C7.78929 2.46061 8 2.96932 8 3.49976V5.99975Z"
        fill="black"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

```js
          <Box flex="1" textAlign="left">
            <Flex flexDirection="row">
              <Text fontWeight="bold" fontSize="1rem">
                채팅
              </Text>
              <Text fontSize="12">
                #{chat.index} {chat.name}(
                <PersonIcon />
                {chat.personnel})
                <LockIcon />
              </Text>
            </Flex>
          </Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Box flex="1" textAlign="left">
      <Flex flexDirection="row">
        <Text fontWeight="bold" fontSize="1rem">
          채팅
        </Text>
        <Text fontSize="12">
          <Flex flexDirection="row">
            <div>
              #{chat.index} {chat.name}(
            </div>
            <PersonIcon />
            <div>{chat.personnel})</div>
            <LockIcon />
          </Flex>
        </Text>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
```

use `<Flex flexDirection="row">` for items on row or use `display: inline` also work for you if you want to do with CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/atinder123/h25Kb/

Comment: Ah.. I didn't put the flex outside the text. It had to be put inside. You can also apply styles to svg! Thank you.